# Printing problems with Espon model ET-2750

Tags: windows-10, network-printer

I have my Epson printer hook up via a wi-fi network. My problem is I keep on receiving errors that my printer is off-line but my printer is on. I did windows troubleshooter and also use Epson troubleshooter but it did not fix this error. I hope someone can give me some real advice to fix my problem. I am also using a desktop PC and 2 laptops in my network. 
Edit 
I had to fix my problem with my wi-fi network. My ISP had to reset my gateway.

Comment: How far away from your wireless access point is the printer?

Comment: my gateway is in the next room. But the wall in between has metal in it. I say my gateway is about 20 or 30 feet away.@spikey_richie

Comment: Can you site the printer next to the router for a day or two, to see if it's a signal strength issue?

Comment: Well, I do have a Wi-fi extender right next to my printer. I printed up a test page from my printer and it shows my signal strength as excellent. What I am thinking that my main router is going bad. Yes, later on, today I will try to move my printer next to my gateway. @spikey_richie

Comment: Oh, OK. I didn't see that extender... /s :)

Comment: I had to fix my problem. My ISP had to reset my gateway to fix my wi-fi.